# regx matching from a file java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to `regx`, but seems to be the only way I can solve the problem i have. 
I was able to extract a text file from a CISCO switch using show vlan. The file looks like below. I just want to extact the vlan number and Name on array of strings. Where to begin.

```
VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    Gi0/1, Gi0/2, Gi0/4, Gi0/5
                                                Gi0/6, Gi0/7, Gi0/8, Gi0/9
                                                Gi0/10, Gi0/11, Gi0/12, Gi0/13
                                                Gi0/14, Gi0/15, Gi0/16, Gi0/17
                                                Gi0/18, Gi0/19, Gi0/20, Gi0/21
                                                Gi0/22, Gi0/23, Gi0/24, Gi0/25
                                                Gi0/26, Gi0/27, Gi0/28, Gi0/29
                                                Gi0/30, Gi0/31, Gi0/32, Gi0/33
                                                Gi0/34, Gi0/35, Gi0/37, Gi0/38
                                                Gi0/39, Gi0/40, Gi0/41, Gi0/42
                                                Gi0/43, Gi0/44, Gi0/45, Gi0/46
                                                Gi0/47, Gi0/48, Gi0/49, Gi0/50
                                                Gi0/51, Gi0/52
2    Test                             active    Gi0/3
3    Internet                         active    Gi0/36
1002 fddi-default                     act/unsup 
1003 token-ring-default               act/unsup 
1004 fddinet-default                  act/unsup 
1005 trnet-default                    act/unsup 

VLAN Type  SAID       MTU   Parent RingNo BridgeNo Stp  BrdgMode Trans1 Trans2
---- ----- ---------- ----- ------ ------ -------- ---- -------- ------ ------
1    enet  100001     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0   
2    enet  100002     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0   
3    enet  100003     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0   
1002 fddi  101002     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0   
1003 tr    101003     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0   
1004 fdnet 101004     1500  -      -      -        ieee -        0      0   
1005 trnet 101005     1500  -      -      -        ibm  -        0      0   

Remote SPAN VLANs
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Primary Secondary Type              Ports
------- --------- ----------------- ------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a straightforward regex -- match start of line; match one or more amount of digits; match any amount whitespace; match one or more amount of letters or hyphens. Put the matches you're interested in into the group

Comment: I have never worked with regx at all... and this seems to be the only solution to my problem. Althouhg the logic is clear to me, i dont know how to write it in regx. I actually just wanted to get the name of the VLan... meaning a word that apears between a number and the word "active"... i have no idea where to begin though.

Answer (score 0):

`^(\d+)\s+([^ ]+)`

And then you will match VLAN number and type OR  VLAN numer and name.
The explanation is in the *first* comment below this question.
The only thing I've changed is that the name or type may contain any characters *except a blank space*.